# Install Ads (Advertising) Server

Tags: ads

I want to install small ads (advertising) server on my local computer, to be run on linux,

is there anybody know the program/tools of it ?.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need a way to receive requests.  A static IP address.  Or a service like No-IP.

Then, you'll need a way to serve the ads.  A server like apache would do fine.  If the ads are static, you're done.

If they need to be dynamic, install PHP or Tomcat (JSP).  Or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need a way to serve the ads, I'd recommend DFP SB. It's a free and simple ad server: www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/index.html